# Amazon EC2 web server unreachable when running

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, web-server

A couple weeks ago I had a service message of "Database error" when I accessed my website hosted on my server. It appeared that MySQL had crashed for some mysterious reason (the had no visitors except me.)

I tried to access it via SSH and found that I could not get in (both Putty and the Java utility). Telnet told me that ports 20-22 were closed I restarted the server. 
When I check now there are no open ports on the server and I cannot ping. I have removed the elastic IP and used the public DNS to check these.

I created an image of my server and launched this as a new instance and was still not able to access it--receiving the same errors.

```
The security group is set to allow 
20  0.0.0.0/0   
21  0.0.0.0/0   
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0   
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0
```

And here is the error I receive using telnet:

```
C:\Users\Wes>telnet 54.235.65.140 22
Connecting To 54.235.65.140...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22:
 Connect failed
```

How is this even possible? How is my server able to receive start/stop/reboot requests if all ports are closed? How do I get it back?

Comment: Well, your first issue is likely that you have opened up your MySQL port to the world. That is a **very** bad idea. Don't do that. There's no good reason whatsoever for it.

Comment: @EEAA it was just for testing. I wanted to see if any ports are accessible.

Comment: What does the console log for this instance say?

Comment: right click on the instance on the aws console and check the o/p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may happen that your instance is in some broken state and it cannot boot up. This would explain the no-connectivity problem.

I suggest to create another clean Virtual Machine from scratch, and attach the suspicious volume as an additional volume, so you can mount it and inspect it. If the host is broken, my recommendation is to copy data and start over.

> How is my server able to receive start/stop/reboot requests if all
>   ports are closed?

Instrumentation of virtual machines is not achieved using your TCP/IP communications with your guest machine. Instead, the virtualization platform (via Amazon internal networks), and the operating system through the virtualization hypervisor, handle start/stop/reboot requests acting directly. Same happens for device snapshots, security groups...: your operating system does not need to be listening: it's all done externally.

Comment: I was able to get logs from Amazon and this is the case. I was able to do as you suggested. I am working on copying directories. No idea why this happened.